# tableUnavailable dependent upon size of search

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm experiencing something rather strange with some queries that I'm performing in BigQuery.

Firstly, I'm using an externally backed table (csv.gz) with about 35 columns. The total data in the location is around 5Gb, with an average file size of 350mb. The reason I'm doing this, is that I continually add data and remove to the table on a rolling basis - to give me a view of the last 7 days of our activity.

When querying, if perform something simple like:

```sql
select * from X limit 10
```

everything works fine. It continues to work fine if you increase the limit up to 1 million rows. As soon as you up the limit to ten million:

```sql
select * from X limit 10000000
```

I end up with a tableUnavailable error "Something went wrong with the table you queried. Contact the table owner for assistance. (error code: tableUnavailable)"

Now according to to any literature on this, this usually results from using some externally owned table (I'm not). I can't find any other enlightening information for this error code.

Basically, If I do anything slightly complex on the data, I get the same result. There's a column called event that has maybe a couple hundred of different values in the entire dataset. If I perform the following:

```sql
select eventType, count(1) from X group by eventType
```

I get the same error.

I'm getting the feeling that this might be related to limits on external tables? Can anybody clarify or shed any light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Doug

Comment: do you have a job id?

Comment: Sure, this one works: acoustic-skein-127515:bquijob_771db2d4_157e7f3218b and this one doesn't: acoustic-skein-127515:bquijob_4bb00e6b_157e7fc3537